# Consistent ST stacking and T-spin

Tags: tetris, tetris-battle

I've got tired of playing tetris like a trained money (just filling up the screen until I can't anymore and then sending combos) so I have it in mind to play by the strategy [outlined here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HVzKVVgy0Mg).

I like the idea, that there's a purposeful and structured way to place the pieces and that its basically possible to play this strategy indefinitely.

Unfortunately, I can't seem to get it right more often than just on the odd occasion. The issue is that I don't get the pieces in a predictable pattern or I'm not able to build the filler space in the first 4 columns from the left because there's a block or two that isn't going to get filled.

A lot of the time I tend to hold pieces and then I get a piece I can't use and so I swap to my Hold piece. In most of these cases, it ends up that my Hold piece isn't one that can fill the gap any better...

It seems like I'm playing against the actual nature of the game here, but I've seen many who can do this consistently.

Can anyone give me any advice here? Basically I'm just wondering if its possible to place the pieces to my advantage regardless of what piece I get and when I get it... Is there something I'm just not seeing?

The image below is an example of a common problem I have... I can't place the green intelligently but I have nowhere to put the red that I have in Hold either

[image: Its a mess]

Comment: psssttt... this is ZT Stacking since the Red piece is a Z;)

Answer (score 1):

If you notice that you have a piece in action that is more useful, and that your piece in hold can fit at the moment, then hold your active piece! It's like when you stack, you realise you have an I-block in your hand. You hold that piece for later tetrises! Do that with your Ts, your Ls and Js, and remove the Os, Ss, and Zs.

Answer (score -3):

I learned ST Stacking from Tetris Wikia, it shows you all the way you can stack it up

http://tetris.wikia.com/wiki/ST_Stacking_Setups
http://tetris.wikia.com/wiki/ST_Stacking

Comment: I went there as well, but haven't managed to put it to good use :/

Comment: You need to test every case stated there in a practice game to get familiar with it. You need to really practice and work on learning ST stacking, its not a "I'll read some guides then I am good to go" type of skills. It requires hard work.

Comment: Well, I found this guide on t-spins which has really helped me improve on those http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ei3fA-xEmAs

Comment: Also found this on ST Stacking which seems to be where most of my problems lie http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LmUeIL62qw8